# I want to align controls that stretches horizontally like google chrome browser address bar

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to align few buttons and a textbox, like the Google Chrome browser address bar, which stretches itself when the user maximizes windows form.

I tried anchor and dock, but 1st control from the left and last control from the right side align themselves but other middle controls stays put.

Please anybody tell me how to properly align controls?

Here's my controls in panel:

[image]

After stretch:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `Dock` property. For the controls before the `TextBox`, leave the `Anchor` property to default, i.e., Left, Top.

For the `TextBox`, set the anchor to Left, Right, Top.

And for controls after the `TextBox`, use Right, Top.

This will resize only the `TextBox` when you change the window size.